# string[] or vector<string>?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector

I have to make this block of "*" made with string, where I know length and height of this rectangle

```
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

I'm wondering which approach should I use, string array or vector of strings(or maybe a third solution?). I'd also like to mention that I'll have to have an access to each "*" by it's coordinates and possibly change it in the following fashion

```
*+*+*
*****
++***
**+**
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use characters instead of strings?

Comment: @Danstahr: No, why would it be

Comment: If width and height are compile-time-constants, consider `std::array`

Comment: @staticx: Maybe because the OP doesn't need strings at all and he's fine with characters? Strings bring additional complexity and overhead to the code.

Comment: Is the size known at compile-time or at run-time? If at compile-time, consider using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), possibly nested with `std::array` of `char`.

Comment: instructions dictate that i must use string(because i also need std::out_of_range later)

Comment: Why you don't use std::string("*******\n*******\n******* .. etc")?

Comment: @Kastaneda how can I then safely access and get the specific char on a certain coordinate

Comment: @user2202368 for access at coordinate (3, 4) `your_string.at(3 * (ROW_LEN + 1) + 4)` where ROW_LEN = 5 (count of asterisk in row) and '+1' is '\n'

Comment: That seems plausible, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `vector<char>`.

Why? Because those aren't real strings. Wrap your 1-D vector with a 2-D data view and you're done.

If you know the size *at compile time*, `std::array` might be an option instead.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `vector<vector<char>>`?

Comment: @matsjoyce No, for various reasons that I guess this comment wouldn't contain. There's a lot of posts on SO regarding that. If I had to pick one, though, `vector<vector<...` implies that the rows might be of different lengths, while in reality they won't/can't.

Comment: It's specified that i use string(i need std::out_of_reach exception later on) and the size is known

Comment: @user2202368 `std::out_of_range` is also thrown by `std::vector`. The interface of both is almost identical. And if it's known, the same goes for `std::array`.

Comment: If anything, simply `std::string` would be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class like this one:

```
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(int w, int h);
    char& at(int x, int y);
    void fill(char value);
private:
    int width;
    int height;
    std::vector<char> vec;
};

// matrix.cpp
Matrix::Matrix(int w, int h)
{
    vec.reserve(w * h);
    width = w;
    height = h;
}

char& Matrix::at(int x, int y)
{
    assert(x < width && y < height && "variable can't be superior to matrix size");
    return vec[x + y * width];
}

void Matrix::fill(char value)
{
    std::fill(vec.begin(), vec.end(), value);
}
```

Comment: You really only need to store either width or height.

Comment: "variable can't be superior to matrix size" hehe that doesn't mean what you think it does, it means variable can't be better than matrix size

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vector (dynamic array) consisting of strings to make this block of * and each position/coordinate can be accessed as arr[i][j] which means the i th row and j th column.

```
Outline of the code: 
      Vector<string> arr;
     string X=" ";
     for(k=0;k<breadth;k++)X+='*';
     //now push X into arr 
     for(k=0;k<length;k++)arr.push_back(X);
      Use two for loops let i and j be the indices of row and col then u can access a particular index (say to change a  * to + on 2 nd row 3rd column)  as 
     arr[i][j]=arr[2][3]='+';
```

Comment: You can use what to do what again?

Comment: Please clarify your answer @soorya.

Comment: @nrussell: I hav modified my answer. If there is any bug plz let me know

Answer (score -1):

If there is need for randomly changing any co-ordinates given (line_no, col_no ) , I would suggest go and wrap around "boost::unordered_map< int, std::string >" ( where int is line no and string is complete string ). It's good performance wise as unordered map internally is based on concept of  hash table.

Comment: I think that's little out of my reach for i am but a mere beginner

Comment: I don't feel that `unordered_map` is a good way to model a 2d array.